# PDDL library for checking/manipulating domains

Tags: python, c++, pddl

Does anybody know a good PDDL library in python or C++ that has the following features

- Parsing of pddl domain/problem files
- Support for ADL (i.e. quantifiers in preconditions and effects)
- Applicability check: A function that tests if a specific grounded action is applicable at the current world state
- Applying actions: A function that applies i.e. manipulate the current world state based on a grounded action
- The possibility to ground an action: A function that generates a list of all possibilities to apply an action on the current world state

This are features that every planner needs but I could not find a library that only does this and all planners that I have found so far are obscure at best.

The closest lib that I could find was pddlpy (https://github.com/hfoffani/pddl-lib), but it does not support ADL and applying actions.

Thanks!

Comment: I created a parser that lets you define the problem and domain as Python classes and then parse them. http://github.com/remykarem/py2pddl. Think it might have some features that you need.